# whose view is not in the window hierarchy in NSNotification

Tags: ios, ios7

I have the Error
whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

When i was NSnotification

```
- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{


    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");


    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    mainTabViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"passID"];
    [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: can you please add more description to your question?

Comment: I want to display my mainTabViewController when the nsnotification occurs

Comment: Is notification getting called?

Comment: Yes called [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                                             selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:)                                                 name:@"TestNotification"                                            object:nil];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to show an activity view inside cell,

 maybe next to title, you could use something like,

```
 UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]     initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
  [cell.imageView addSubview:activityView];
  [activityView startAnimating];
```